# nopcommerce API convert Grant_type code to password

Tags: nopcommerce

Currently nopcommerce api need client_id and redirect url but i want it convert only user name and password.
I want to send user id and password it should return accesstoken back to me.

Comment: First, which version? second, are you using any plugin? if you're using nopTemplates plugin, refactor the code, remove oAuth and add JWT or your custom code.

Comment: I am using api plugin.

Comment: This one? https://github.com/SevenSpikes/api-plugin-for-nopcommerce

Comment: Which nop verison?